# React Native AWS Amplify AuthError : Amplify has not been configured correctly

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS Amplify library in my react native project with manual configuration to sign in. I'm able to login in android application with react native project, but when i run the same react native code in ios, i'm getting the below error. I'm fetching my amplify configuration params data from .env files in react native.

I have followed these steps for iOS pod install for setting up the Amplify library
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js#configure-your-application

I have installed all the pods in iOS related to https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-config and amplify libraries.

```
// import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
   import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core';
   import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';

  /** Configration of Cognito Auth Process for mobile client */
    Amplify.configure({
      Auth: {

  // REQUIRED only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
  identityPoolId: Config.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,

  // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
  region:  Config.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_REGION,

  // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
  userPoolId: Config.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,

  // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
  userPoolWebClientId: Config.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_WEB_CLIENT_ID,

  // OPTIONAL - Enforce user authentication prior to accessing AWS resources or not
  mandatorySignIn: false,

  // OPTIONAL - Manually set the authentication flow type. Default is 'USER_SRP_AUTH'
  authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',

   // OPTIONAL - Hosted UI configuration
  oauth: {
      domain: Config.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_OAUTH_DOMAIN,
      scope: ['openid', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
      redirectSignIn: Config.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_OAUTH_REDIRECT_SIGNIN,
      redirectSignOut: Config.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_OAUTH_REDIRECT_SIGNOUT,
      responseType: Config.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_OAUTH_RESPONSE_TYPE, // or 'token', note 
      that REFRESH token will only be generated when the responseType is code
     }
     }.   
   });

   // You can get the current config object
    const currentConfig = Auth.configure();

  //Usage
   Auth.signIn(username, password).then(
    (result) => {
      console.log(result);
      if(result instanceof CognitoUser){
        console.log(result.getSignInUserSession()?.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
        console.log(result.getSignInUserSession()?.getIdToken());
        console.log(result.getSignInUserSession()?.getRefreshToken());
      }
      this.props.navigation.replace('ChangePassword');
    }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      console.log('################# SignIn Error :');
      console.log(error);
    }
  )
   } catch (exception) {
  console.log(exception);
     console.log('################# Exception in SignIn API call');
    }
```

Not able to figure out what was the issue.

```
 [ERROR] 27:54.153 AuthError - 
        Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly. 
        The configuration object is missing required auth properties. 
        Did you run `amplify push` after adding auth via `amplify add auth`?
        See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#amplify-project-setup for 
   more information
```

Please let me know why exactly the above code is showing error when i run in iOS.

Comment: Have you tried `process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_REGION` instead of `Config.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_REGION`?

Answer (score 1):

I had issue with react-native-config setup for android. I forget to do this  [extra step for android](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#advanced-android-setup). My config was undefined

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating my version of Amplify. I deleted the node_modues folder and package-lock.json. I ran 'npm install' and that fixed it.